# Make a Number field like "10,000.0000" when focusout in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

In Oracle APEX -
I tried to put below JS in Advance-> Custom Attributes property- onfocusout="this.value=Number(this.value).toFixed(4).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')"

and in Appearance-> Format mask -> 999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G990D0000

but in this JS, I am getting result like- 10,000.0,000

I need result as comma separated like- 999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G990D0000 e.g. 10,000.0000

Note: Decimal should be fixed 4 and rest values should be thousand separator.
Please help me if you ever tried this.

Type-> NumberFormat{Plug In} is not working in this case, As I am getting the records from interactive report to update.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Checkout the format money post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings/149099#149099  you can probably use something like formatMoney(this.value,4) and get the result you need in JS.

Comment: This(formatMoney(this.value,4)) is not working in APEX.

Comment: onfocusout="this.value=Number(this.value).toFixed(4).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')"
Above solution is working but result is not as expected.

Comment: you need to include the formatMoney javacript code in your application's javascript.  Either on the page or as a static file.  And "Above solution is working but result is not as expected" = not working.  The reason it doesn't work is because the regex is looking for 3 digits and adding a comma and there are multiple sets of 3 digits.  You can see the format money solution to see how that user wrote his regex if you prefer to continue with that solution but it seems more difficult.

Comment: What is your version of apex ? This works for me as you describe out of the box- no custom coding needed. Page item of type "Number Field", format mask "999G999G999G999G990D0000". If I put in "10000" and click anywhere else, the format changes to "10,000.0000". I tested on 20.2

Comment: My version is 20.2 as well. But when I put Number field in page item type then it's working. But when I click on edit of interactive report then it fills the data in my form. After that if I try to update the amount column, it's not displaying as 10,000.0000

Comment: I want like whenever I update the amount and I click anywhere, it should be in this format  999G999G999G999G990D0000 only.

Comment: When I use js -onfocusout="this.value=Number(this.value).toFixed(4).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')"                                               it's giving me fixed 4 decimal but it's separates the number of counut of 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of custom coding to achieve this.

Please put the format mask as 999G999G999G999G990D0000 in the Number Field.